# How to find all elements with inner text in jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is the jquery to find all elements that contain inner text?

`$("*:contains(*)")` just seems wrong...

Comment: Have you tried finding all the textNodes of the document and finding their parents?

Comment: @DavidThomas - umm, provide some code pls.

Comment: If you really need to find **all** elements that contains some text, you're probably doing something wrong, as it's not really something that would normally be very useful, and using the asterix selector should give most people a little chill, as it can be very expensive on larger documents.

Comment: I am writing an extension that detects chinese characters and converts the text into ruby elements with the pinyin on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is "inner text"? Is it something like this you want to do?

```
var elems = [];
$('*').each(function(){
    if ($(this).text().length > 0) {
        elems.push($(this));
    }
});

console.log('Elements with text: ' + elems.length);
console.log('All elements with text:' + elems);
```

Comment: Oh sorry, wrong syntax, it is late here in sweden :) http://fiddle.jshell.net/GmTcw/4/

Comment: If only elements in the body, use "body > *"

Like this http://fiddle.jshell.net/GmTcw/5/

Comment: no problems, you can also use "body *", that will go through every children and not just the "top".

Answer (score 1):

`$.filter("*")` will do what you're looking for.

Example using `innerHTML`:

```
$(document.getElementById("elementID").innerHTML).filter("*");
```

Comment: Ben you are right, yours is an even more elegant solution. the other one also works though, and it is first. honestly if I didnt have problems implementing it, I would have given you credit instead of asking you to check the fiddle... sorry bud, if I could I'd give you credit too

Answer (score 0):

If having "inner text" is defined as having a text node, I think this will do what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/TMyRr/

```
var $elementsWithTextNodes = $('*').filter(function(){
    return $(this).contents().filter(function() {
       return this.nodeType == 3 && $.trim($(this).text()) != ''; 
    }).length;
});
```

Comment: that's interesting. it gives me many tags that it should not though, like script and style and title. changing the context from "*" to "body" didn't detect _any_ divs, p's, etc. http://fiddle.jshell.net/M29za/

Comment: @robertotomás `$('body')` only selects one element, try `$('body *')`